# how does share it application use our information?

Tags: applications, shareit

I would like to know, does share it application store our photos and videos on its server since it has access to phone's gallery

Comment: http://w.ushareit.com/w/privacy/a/

Comment: I read their privacy policy. But by personal information, do they mean photos and videos aswell?

Comment: That's really a question for them, or a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

But it's said in their TOS. Please refer it here.
[image: From SHAREit TOS]

Answer (score 0):

No, when you share files, the two devices work by creating a hotspot on one device, and connecting to it on the other. This way, the data is transmitted from one phone to another using the Wi-Fi network, and no data is sent to any servers. This is why they make it clear that no mobile data is needed.