# Does ShareIt use the content we share?

Tags: security, android-pc, file-sharing, shareit

In the TOS it seems they say that we give right to use our content.

[image: From SHAREit TOS]

Comment: wow, you are reading this!? thumbs up! :D yes. same for whatsapp facebook instagram tiktok and all this sh\*t except they may have striked (a) and (b) already ;)

Comment: Glad you asked +1. See the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHAREit#:~:text=On%20June%2029%2C%202020%2C%20the,though%20no%20evidence%20was%20 provided) including the references// Check the app permissions and report on Exodus https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/analysis/submit/ //Once you are convinced write an answer yourself! We welcome it :)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [how does share it application use our information?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/169322/44325)

Comment: As FYI, that app is poison and Indian Government banned that app (there are other factors too for this decision)